# Valgrind Shows Invalid read at beginning of While Loop

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a Invalid Read Error shown on the line of the comparitor of a while loop. The weird thing is I check the variables used in the comparitor of the loop at the bottom and they're fine there but then they read invalidly when the while loop compares them at the top. Something must happen to them in between the bottom of the loop and the top again but I dont know what.

Here is the function containing the faulty loop:

```
void keyMatch(Block * Buff, Key key, int * buff_fill, int * Buff_size){
    int k = 0;
printf("k:%i buff fill:%i, then %i\n",k,*buff_fill,(k)<(*buff_fill));fflush(stdout);
    while((k)<(*buff_fill)){
        if(block_addable(key,Buff[k])){
            bufadd(Buff,key,k,buff_fill,Buff_size);
            }
        k++;
        printf("k:%i ",k);fflush(stdout);
        printf("buff fill:%i",*buff_fill);fflush(stdout);
        printf("then %i\n",(k)<(*buff_fill));fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("done\n");fflush(stdout);
}
```

Here is the function which increments *buff_fill:

```
void bufadd(Block * Buff , Key key,int buff_index, int * buff_fill, int * Buff_size){
    if(*buff_fill==(*Buff_size)){
        Buff = (Block*) realloc(Buff,2*(*Buff_size)*sizeof(Block));
        (*Buff_size) =(*Buff_size)*2;
    }

    Buff[*buff_fill]=Buff[buff_index];
    Buff[*buff_fill].Keys[Buff[*buff_fill].fill]=key;
    Buff[*buff_fill].fill++;
   (*buff_fill)=(*buff_fill)+1;

}
```

Here is the segment of the Valgrind memory checker showing the Invalid read:

```
k: 0 buff fill: 26, then 1
k: 1 buff fill: 27 then 1
k: 2 buff fill: 28 then 1
k: 3 buff fill: 29 then 1 ==
3845 == Invalid read of size 8 ==
3845 == at 0x4013B0: keyMatch(main.c: 225) ==
3845 == by 0x40167D: getBlocks(main.c: 260) ==
3845 == by 0x400A1B: main(main.c: 362) ==
3845 == Address 0x83d6130 is 240 bytes inside a block of size 2, 240 free 'd ==
3845 == at 0x4C2DEAE: realloc( in /usr/lib / valgrind / vgpreload_memcheck - amd64 - linux.so) ==
3845 == by 0x4012BF: bufadd(main.c: 198) ==
3845 == by 0x401452: keyMatch(main.c: 227) ==
3845 == by 0x40167D: getBlocks(main.c: 260) ==
3845 == by 0x400A1B: main(main.c: 362) ==
3845 ==
```

Here is the rest of the c code but I don't believe its relevant to the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>

double dia = 0.000001;

typedef struct {
    long ID;
    float value;
}Key;

Key ** Keys;

typedef struct {
    int fill;
    long signature;
    Key Keys[4];
}Block;

typedef struct{
    long signture;
    Block * Blocks;
}Group;

//Function used as a tool in getExpectedBlocks to help determine the maximum possible ammount of block
 unsigned long long nChoosek( unsigned n, unsigned k ){
    if (k > n) return 0;
    if (k * 2 > n) k = n-k;
    if (k == 0) return 1;

    unsigned long long result = n;
    for( int i = 2; i <= k; ++i ) {
        result *= (n-i+1);
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}

//Finds the most probable ammount of Blocks in the database, value is used for memory allocation
int getExpectedBlocks(int rows){
double largest = 0;

    for(int i =1 ; i < 4 ; i++){
    double size = nChoosek(rows,i+1);
        for (int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
        size *= (2*dia);
        }
        if(size>largest){
        largest=size;

        }
    }
return largest;
}

//Gets the dimensions of the database and obviously the keys as well, mainly used for memopry allocation
int * getDimensions(){
int * dimensions = (int*) calloc(2, sizeof(int));
dimensions[0]=0;
dimensions[1]=0;

FILE *fp;
  if ((fp = fopen("data.txt","r")) != NULL)
    {
            int rows=0;
            int numbers=0;
            char c;
            while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
                if(c=='\n'){
                rows++;
                }
                if((c=='\n')||(c==',')){
                numbers++;
                }
            }
            dimensions[0]=rows;
            dimensions[1]=numbers/rows;
    }
    else{
    printf("data.txt failed to open");
        exit(1);
    }
  fclose(fp);

return dimensions;
}

//Get an array of doubles containing all the rowIDs
long * getIDs(int rows){
  FILE *fp;
  long *rowIDs;
  if ((fp = fopen("keys.txt","r")) != NULL)
    {
    //Allocate memory for all the rowIDs
    rowIDs = (long*) calloc(rows, sizeof(long));

    //Fill rowIDs with the actual IDs
        char c;
        int ID_pos = 0;
        int rowIDs_index = 0;
        char ID[15]="";
        //char * p;
        while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
            if(isdigit(c)){
            ID[ID_pos]=c;
            ID_pos++;
            }
            if(ID_pos==14){
            rowIDs[rowIDs_index]=atol(ID);
            rowIDs_index++;
            strcpy(ID,"00000000000000");
            ID_pos=0;
            }
        }

    }
    else{
    printf("keys.txt failed to open");
        exit(1);
    }

  fclose(fp);
  return rowIDs;
}

//Get a 2D array of floats containing all keys in their respective columns
float ** getValues(int rows, int columns){
 FILE *fp;
  float **Values;
  if ((fp = fopen("data.txt","r")) != NULL)
    {
    //Allocate memory for all the Values
    Values = (float**)calloc(columns, sizeof(float*));
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {

    Values[i] = (float*)calloc(rows, sizeof(float));
    }

    //Fill Values with the actual Values
        char c;
        int value_pos = 0;
        int row_index = 0;
        int column_index = 0;
        char value[9]="";
        char * p;
        while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){

            if((isdigit(c))||(c=='.')){
            value[value_pos]=c;
            value_pos++;
            }

            if(!((isdigit(c))||(c=='.'))&&(c!=13)){
            Values[column_index][row_index]=strtof(value,&p);
            column_index++;
            strcpy(value,"00000000");
            value_pos=0;
            }

            if(c=='\n'){
            column_index=0;
            row_index++;
            }
        }

    }
    else{
    printf("data.txt failed to open");
        exit(1);
    }

  fclose(fp);
  return Values;
}

Key ** makeDatabase(long * rowIDs, float ** Values, int rows, int columns){
    Key ** Keys = (Key**)calloc(columns, sizeof(Key*));
        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            Keys[i] = (Key*)calloc(rows, sizeof(Key));
        }

    for(int col = 0 ; col < columns ; col++){
        for(int row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++){
        Keys[col][row].ID= rowIDs[row];
        Keys[col][row].value=Values[col][row];
        }
    }

return Keys;
}

void bufadd(Block * Buff , Key key,int buff_index, int * buff_fill, int * Buff_size){
    if(*buff_fill==(*Buff_size)){
        Buff = (Block*) realloc(Buff,2*(*Buff_size)*sizeof(Block));
        (*Buff_size) =(*Buff_size)*2;
    }

    Buff[*buff_fill]=Buff[buff_index];
    Buff[*buff_fill].Keys[Buff[*buff_fill].fill]=key;
    Buff[*buff_fill].fill++;
   (*buff_fill)=(*buff_fill)+1;

}

int block_addable(Key addkey, Block block){
    if(block.fill>3){
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < block.fill ; i++){
        if(block.Keys[i].ID==addkey.ID){
        return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;

}

void keyMatch(Block * Buff, Key key, int * buff_fill, int * Buff_size){
    int k = 0;
printf("k:%i buff fill:%i, then %i\n",k,*buff_fill,(k)<(*buff_fill));fflush(stdout);
    while((k)<(*buff_fill)){
        if(block_addable(key,Buff[k])){
            bufadd(Buff,key,k,buff_fill,Buff_size);
            }
        k++;
        printf("k:%i ",k);fflush(stdout);
        printf("buff fill:%i",*buff_fill);fflush(stdout);
        printf("then %i\n",(k)<(*buff_fill));fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("done\n");fflush(stdout);
}

Block * getBlocks(Key * column, int ExpectedBlocks, int rows, int * blocks){

    Block * Blocks = (Block*)calloc(ExpectedBlocks, sizeof(Block));
    int Blocks_size = ExpectedBlocks;

    //Buff = realloc(Buff,ExpectedBlocks*sizeof(Block));
    int Buff_size = ExpectedBlocks;
    int * buff_fill = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *buff_fill=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows ; i++){
        Block * Buff = (Block*)calloc(ExpectedBlocks, sizeof(Block));
        //add the 'self' block to the possible blocks buff
        Buff[0].Keys[0]=column[i];
        Buff[0].fill=1;
        *buff_fill=1;

        //check if the next key is in neighborhood


        int j = i+1;
        while((j<rows)&&((fabsf(column[i].value-column[j].value))<dia)){
            //add match to possible blocks buffer
            keyMatch(Buff,column[j],buff_fill,&Buff_size);
            j++;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < *buff_fill ; j++){
           // printf("%i Buff No. %i  ",i,j);
                for(int x = 0 ; x < Buff[j].fill ; x++){
                  //  printf("%f ",Buff[j].Keys[x].value);
                    }
                  //  printf("\n");
        }

        //clear buffer whilst extracting full blocks
        for(int j = 0 ; j <*buff_fill ; j++){
            //add full blocks to blocks
            if(Buff[j].fill==4){
                //check if Block is large enough for the values being added and expands if neccessary
                if(*blocks==(Blocks_size)){
                    //printf("block realloc during %i in... %i/%i..",i,*blocks,Blocks_size);fflush(stdout);
                    Blocks =(Block*) realloc(Blocks,2*Blocks_size*sizeof(Block));
                    //printf("out\n");fflush(stdout);
                    Blocks_size=2*Blocks_size;
                }
                //printf("block adding during %i in... %i/%i..",i,*blocks,Blocks_size);fflush(stdout);
                Blocks[*blocks]=Buff[j];
                (*blocks)=(*blocks)+1;
                //printf("out\n");fflush(stdout);
            }
            //Buff[j].fill=0;


         }

         //printf("begi in %i ...",i);fflush(stdout);
         free(Buff);
         //rintf("done\n");fflush(stdout);
    }
    return Blocks;
}

int cmpkeys(const void *a, const void *b){
const Key* ka = (Key*)a;
const Key* kb = (Key*)b;
  return (ka->value > kb->value) - (ka->value < kb->value);
}

void setsignatures(Block * Blocks,int blocks){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < blocks ; i++){
        long sig = 0;
        for(int j = 0 ; j <4 ; j++){
            sig += Blocks[i].Keys[j].ID;
        }
        Blocks[i].signature=sig;
    }
}

Group * getGroups(Block ** AllBlocks){
    Group * Groups;

    return Groups;
}

int main(){
float fudgefactor = 1.5;


//Determine how many dimensions for preallocation of memory
    int * dimensions = getDimensions();
    int rows = dimensions[0];
    int columns = dimensions[1];
//Load the RowIDs into an Array
    long * rowIDs = getIDs(rows);

//Load the Keys into an Array
   float ** Values =getValues(rows,columns);

//Generate database of all Keys
    Keys = makeDatabase(rowIDs,Values,rows,columns);
    //printf("first value is %f",Keys[0][0].value);

    free(Values);
    free(rowIDs);

    Block ** AllBlocks = (Block**)calloc(columns, sizeof(Key*));

//Determine Expected number of blocks per column for predictable memory allocation
    int ExpectedBlocks = fudgefactor*getExpectedBlocks(rows);

//this array stores the number of blocks in each column
    int * blocks = (int*)calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
//IN parallel, organise then find the blocks in the columns
    int i;
//#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0  ; i < columns; i++){
         qsort(Keys[i],rows,sizeof(Key),cmpkeys);
    }
//#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0  ; i < columns; i++){
    //Sort Keys by values Database for easier search pattern
        //Search for and list blocks in Keys[i]
        printf("column:%i\n",i);
        int blocks=0;
        Block * Blocks = getBlocks(Keys[i],ExpectedBlocks,rows,&blocks);
        setsignatures(Blocks,blocks);
        AllBlocks[i]= Blocks;
        for(int j = 0; j < blocks ; j++){
            printf("%i Blocks No. %i  ",i,j);
                for(int x = 0 ; x < 4 ; x++){
                    printf("%f ",Blocks[j].Keys[x].value);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
        }
    }

    //Put all Blocks in Groups
    //Group * Groups = getGroups(AllBlocks);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ps the line main.c:225 is this line: 'while((k)<(*buff_fill)){'

Comment: nm found the problem, wasnt updating the pointer to the buffer when i realloced it.